# Save items on my ArrayList (Adding keeps replacing the first one)

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I'm trying to create an app that shows the employee of a store the steps to follow to assist the customer. It shows the questions that the employee must ask in order to understand what the customer needs.

The problem is that when I try to select a product I add it to a ListView using ArrayList. I can add one Product but when i Try to add a second one it just replaces the first one I added.

Code for Sellador.java (Where I choose the product to add)

```
public class Sellador extends AppCompatActivity {

    String codigo,nombreproducto;
    int ident,imagen,first;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sellador);

    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.selladorbco){
            codigo = "600706";
            nombreproducto = "Prueba desde boton sellador bco";
            ident = 4;
            imagen = R.drawable.guy1;
            Intent agg2 = new Intent(this,ListaProductos.class);
            agg2.putExtra("codigo",codigo);
            agg2.putExtra("nombreproducto",nombreproducto);
            agg2.putExtra("identificador",ident);
            agg2.putExtra("imagen",imagen);
            startActivity(agg2);
        }
        if(v.getId() == R.id.selladortrans){
            codigo = "600705";
            nombreproducto = "Prueba desde boton sellador trans";
            ident = 2;
            imagen = R.drawable.guy1;
            Intent agg = new Intent(this,ListaProductos.class);
            agg.putExtra("codigo",codigo);
            agg.putExtra("nombreproducto",nombreproducto);
            agg.putExtra("identificador",ident);
            agg.putExtra("imagen",imagen);
            startActivity(agg);

        }
        if(v.getId() == R.id.botonlista){
            Intent cambiolista = new Intent(this, ListaProductos.class);
            startActivity(cambiolista);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for ListaProductos.java (Where I show the ListView of products)

```
public class ListaProductos extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String codigo,nombreproducto;
    public int ident,imagen;
    public  ListView listaDatos;
    public  ArrayList<Producto> Lista;
    public Adaptador miadaptador;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_productos);
        aggPrimerProducto();

    }

    public void aggPrimerProducto(){
        listaDatos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDatos);
        Lista = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        miadaptador = new Adaptador(this,Lista);
        listaDatos.setAdapter(miadaptador);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        codigo = extras.getString("codigo");
        nombreproducto = extras.getString("nombreproducto");
        ident = extras.getInt("ident");
        imagen = extras.getInt("imagen");
        agregarProducto(codigo,ident,imagen,nombreproducto);
    }

    public void agregarProducto(String code, int ident, int image, String name){

        Lista.add(new Producto(code,ident,image,name));
        miadaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.botonsig){
            agregarProducto("66666",5,R.drawable.guy1,"Prueba con boton existente");

        }
    }
}
```

Code for Adapter:

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    Context contexto;
    List<Producto> ListaObjetos;

    public Adaptador(Context contexto, List<Producto> listaObjetos) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        ListaObjetos = listaObjetos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ListaObjetos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return ListaObjetos.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return ListaObjetos.get(i).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View vista = view;

        LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
        vista = inflate.inflate(R.layout.itemlistview,viewGroup,false);

        ImageView imagen = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.imagenProducto);
        TextView codigo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);
        TextView nombre = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);

        codigo.setText(ListaObjetos.get(i).getCodigo());
        nombre.setText(ListaObjetos.get(i).getNombre());
        imagen.setImageResource(ListaObjetos.get(i).getImagen());

        return vista;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your Adapter code as well

Comment: Better still, a [mcve].

Comment: I have edited the question and added the Adapter code at the bottom, thanks! I will try to create a minimal version of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line

```
miadaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with this

```
listaDatos.setAdapter(miadaptador);
```

in your `agregarProducto()` method

Comment: Same thing keeps happening, I can add new products while on the ListView activity, but when I try to add a new product from another activity it resets.

Answer (score 0):

That is the way your implement.

In `Sellador` view, you select a product. and then it opens `ListaProductos` view.

Every time open the `ListaProductos` view, you initialized an empty `ArrayList<Producto> Lista` and you add the product you selected from `Sellador` view.

That is the reason it only shows one product which is your recently selected.

Comment: Where should I put the Lista = new ArrayList<Producto>(); if I don't want it to create a new empty ArrayList everytime I open the ListaProductos view?

Comment: try to store the products in a static ArrayList or in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you add a new product to your arraylist it increases the length? Or just stays the same?

Comment: It stays the same, it happens when I try to add a product outside of the Product List view, if I add a button to add a product inside of the Product List view I can add more than one